# Upgrade Magento while keeping all order data, sales data, ect

Tags: magento, upgrade

Is there a definitive way to upgrade Magento while keeping all order data, sales data, ect?

After setting up a staging environment and ensuring all extensions, ect. are working properly there will inevitably be orders placed, orders processed, ect. Is there a proper way to sync the data with the production installation?

An alternative way I've read about is to set up a staging area and essentially practice the upgrade while taking notes on all the fixes that need to be completed. Then put the site into maintenance mode and do the upgrade on in the production environment. Is this a viable solution?

Any insight is appreciated.

- Dane

Comment: There's a StackExchange site specifically for Magento: [magento.se] You probably do better asking there.

Answer (score 0):

With most magento updates you just need to ensure that you are pointing to the same database in your local.xml file. Magento will run all updates needed on that database to get it up to speed automatically. Yay!

However. Back up that database *before* the update runs. If you have any issues, you want to make sure you have a clean version.

The update often uses a *lot* of memory if you have many items/orders. So make sure your .htaccess file (which might have been overwritten by the update) still has a good amount of memory allocated.